# Excel VBA Chrome Selenium Cannot click button

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Chrome can click the Log in button if using ChromeNoCache sub.  But Chrome cannot click the Log in button if using the ChromeCache sub, and I cannot figure out why.  Please help make it click the Log in button.

```
Public WD As New WebDriver

Sub ChromeNoCache() 'browser does NOT remember user and password for subsequent logins
        Call seleniumnocache("https://tap.revenue.wi.gov/mta/_/")
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-5").SendKeys "user"
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-6").SendKeys "password"
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-7").click  'This click works fine
End sub
Sub ChromeCache() 'browser remembers user and password for subsequent logins
        Call selenium("https://tap.revenue.wi.gov/mta/_/")
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-5").SendKeys "user"
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-6").SendKeys "password"
            WD.FindElementById("Dd-7").click  'This click is ignored by Chrome and does not work
End sub
Sub Selenium(curl)  'web will not ask for security code in subsequent logins
    On Error GoTo d1
    usernam = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName  '.ComputerName   .UserDomain
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    spath = "C:\Users\" & usernam & "\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic"  ' shm.Range ("i3")
    oShell.Run "chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir=""""" & spath & """"""
    Set oShell = Nothing
    WD.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014"
    WD.Start "Chrome", ""
    GoTo d2
    d1:
    WD.Start "Chrome", ""
    d2:
    WD.Get curl
End Sub

Sub seleniumnocache(curl)
    WD.Start "Chrome", ""
    WD.Get curl
End Sub
```